# Can I change a string in parsed text using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building a simple weather app using the [openweathermap](http://api.openweathermap.org) api and I'd like to be able to change the values returned to something else. I thought the problem was with changing text that isn't static and I tried this method `return text.replace("Today", "Hello world");` http://jsfiddle.net/D63d8/ on my problem and it didn't work. Is it possible to change parsed text or am I clutching at straws here?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="weather">

        <ul id="scroller">
        </ul>

        <a href="#" class="arrow previous">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="arrow next">Next</a>

    </div>

    <p class="location"></p>

    <div id="clouds"></div>

    <!-- JavaScript includes - jQuery, moment.js and our own script.js -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.0.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
    $(function(){

        /* Configuration */

        var DEG = 'c';          // c for celsius, f for fahrenheit

        var weatherDiv = $('#weather'),
            scroller = $('#scroller'),
            location = $('p.location');

        // Does this browser support geolocation?
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError);
        }
        else{
            showError("Your browser does not support Geolocation!");
        }

        // Get user's location, and use OpenWeatherMap
        // to get the location name and weather forecast

        function locationSuccess(position) {

            try{

                // Retrive the cache
                var cache = localStorage.weatherCache && JSON.parse(localStorage.weatherCache);

                var d = new Date();

                // If the cache is newer than 30 minutes, use the cache
                if(cache && cache.timestamp && cache.timestamp > d.getTime() - 30*60*1000){

                    // Get the offset from UTC (turn the offset minutes into ms)
                    var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
                    var city = cache.data.city.name;
                    var country = cache.data.city.country;

                    $.each(cache.data.list, function(){
                        // "this" holds a forecast object

                        // Get the local time of this forecast (the api returns it in utc)
                        var localTime = new Date(this.dt*1000 - offset);

                        addWeather(
                            this.weather[0].icon,
                            moment(localTime).calendar(),   // We are using the moment.js library to format the date
                            this.weather[0].main + ' <b>' + convertTemperature(this.main.temp_min) + '°' + DEG +
                                                    ' / ' + convertTemperature(this.main.temp_max) + '°' + DEG+'</b>'
                        );

                    });

                    // Add the location to the page
                    location.html(city+', <b>'+country+'</b>');

                    weatherDiv.addClass('loaded');

                    // Set the slider to the first slide
                    showSlide(0);

                }

                else{

                    // If the cache is old or nonexistent, issue a new AJAX request

                    var weatherAPI = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat='+position.coords.latitude+
                                        '&lon='+position.coords.longitude+'&callback=?'

                    $.getJSON(weatherAPI, function(response){

                        // Store the cache
                        localStorage.weatherCache = JSON.stringify({
                            timestamp:(new Date()).getTime(),   // getTime() returns milliseconds
                            data: response
                        });

                        // Call the function again
                        locationSuccess(position);
                    });
                }

            }
            catch(e){
                showError("We can't find information about your city!");
                window.console && console.error(e);
            }
        }

        function addWeather(icon, day, condition){

            var markup = '<li>'+
                '<img src="assets/img/icons/'+ icon +'.png" />'+
                ' <p class="day">'+ day +'</p> <p class="cond">'+ condition +
                '</p></li>';

            scroller.append(markup);

        }


        /* Handling the previous / next arrows */

        var currentSlide = 0;
        weatherDiv.find('a.previous').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            showSlide(currentSlide-1);
        });

        weatherDiv.find('a.next').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            showSlide(currentSlide+1);
        });


        // listen for arrow keys

        $(document).keydown(function(e){
            switch(e.keyCode){
                case 37: 
                    weatherDiv.find('a.previous').click();
                break;
                case 39:
                    weatherDiv.find('a.next').click();
                break;
            }
        });

        function showSlide(i){
            var items = scroller.find('li');

            if (i >= items.length || i < 0 || scroller.is(':animated')){
                return false;
            }

            weatherDiv.removeClass('first last');

            if(i == 0){
                weatherDiv.addClass('first');
            }
            else if (i == items.length-1){
                weatherDiv.addClass('last');
            }

            scroller.animate({left:(-i*100)+'%'}, function(){
                currentSlide = i;
            });
        }


        /* Error handling functions */

        function locationError(error){
            switch(error.code) {
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    showError("A timeout occured! Please try again!");
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    showError('We can\'t detect your location. Sorry!');
                    break;
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    showError('Please allow geolocation access for this to work.');
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    showError('An unknown error occured!');
                    break;
            }

        }

        function convertTemperature(kelvin){
            // Convert the temperature to either Celsius or Fahrenheit:
            return Math.round(DEG == 'c' ? (kelvin - 273.15) : (kelvin*9/5 - 459.67));
        }

        function showError(msg){
            weatherDiv.addClass('error').html(msg);
        }

    });

   $(".day").text(function(index, text) {
      return text.replace("Today", "Hello world");
    });
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U7tcX)

Comment: That is a lot of code, where do you want to replace what?

Comment: Your replace function gets run before those elements exist, you'll need to do the replace where you append `markup`, though it might need to go into a `ready` event listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to replace the text you have to do it after the JSON has been parsed to HTML (ie it must go in the `locationSuccess()` function).
[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8fFzK/) (text replace moved to line 60).

A better approach is probably to modify the JSON directly after you receive it, but that requires a bit more code.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after? That's a lot of code to look through.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D63d8/1/) On click it will use `text.replace`.

Comment: Hi @speak, thanks for your answer but my problem is in the second JSFiddle, the first one was an example of an attempt I'd made